# How to configure Adobe Reader DC to open full-screen?

Tags: viewers, adobe

I have TeXnicCenter 2.0 configured to use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC but Adobe opens the PDF file with magnification of 56.9% and also includes bookmark tabs on the left side and another Adobe tab on the right side of the screen ending up with a small view of my PDF file which I then have to manually remove the tabs and increase the magnification manually which is time-consuming as I will have to do this many times during the day while creating a paper.  I would like it to default without these tabs with the file extending across the screen.  This turns out to be a magnification of 152%.

Is is possible to set up the reader this way?  I have tried editing the various preferences of the reader without success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show your configuration in screenshots?

Comment: How is this related to (La)TeX? Acrobat Reader DC settings you can do in it (see Edit/Preference).

Comment: you set a few options with hyperref in the document, e.g. `\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH}`

Comment: If you need to do this several times a day, why do you even use Acrobat for a quick glance at your PDF and not slimmer viewer with better start up time and less convoluted interface? (Disclaimer: I'm not a fan of Acrobat)